# Microsoft Azure Active Directory

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, azure-active-directory

Im kinda new to Windows server, but have been checking out Microsoft Azure and like the IaaS.

Just a question about SSO verse Azure Active Directory Sync.

Im moving my infrastructure into Azure, my base is a AD server, "dirsync" or AD FS server and a few web servers etc. We use Google Apps for Email, Calendar and Drive.

So I see that there are two ways to keep my AD directory and Azure directory in sync. SSO and Azure Active Directory Sync.

**If I use Azure Active Directory Sync and not setup AD FS on a server with SSO, will I still be able to use SSO with my Azure Directory to Apps the Microsoft have in the Azure portal?**

The only reason I would need a AD FS server if I had Apps/Services on site that I wanted to use SSO with, correct?

I plan to run, kayako and CrashPlan in two VM's in Azure. Both will use LDAP/AD for usernames/password authentication. But would be cool to get SSO for both webapps so employees can sing-on via the myapps.microsoft.com portal.

Answer (score -1):

The two ways are DirSync and AAD Sync. Refer: [Synchronization Previews Now Available for Microsoft Azure Active Directory](http://redmondmag.com/articles/2014/04/22/dirsync-microsoft-azure.aspx).

- Sync = Same Sign On between on-premise and cloud
- Sync + ADFS = Single Sign On between on-premise and cloud

**Update**

myapps.microsoft.com is for third-party vendors like SalesForce who have asked Microsoft to add them as a SaaS application to AAD. It's not for company specific apps.

For company specific apps., you need ADFS as above.

Having done that, if your user SSO's into your app. and then wants to use e.g. SalesForce, they won't have to login again.

Comment: So if I have two web apps that both support SSO hosted in a VM in the cloud. Would I need a ADFS server in the private cloud so those two apps could use SSO when users go to myapps.microsoft.com?

Or can I get those two apps to user Azure Active Directory to do SSO? without the need on a AD FS server and just use Directory Sync?

Comment: okay, cool thank you! so If I add a AD FS server. And configure some on-site apps will they show up in the myapps.microsoft.com portal?

Comment: No - that's only for SaaS apps. Here's the list - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/gallery/active-directory/#all. That list has nothing to do with ADFS.

Comment: SO theres no way at all to add in house apps to the myapps.microsoft.com portal? and achieve SSO... 

http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/06/10/public-preview-of-azure-ad-application-proxy.aspx?pi145073=2#pi145073=2#comments

Comment: If you look at the link above down the bottom you'll see "Application publishers Learn how to integrate with Active Directory and be listed here". That's how you get added.